# Move all the file present in a directory with same letter/word in them to another directory

Tags: directory, mv

```
rda@MacBook-Pro X.WORK % ls

Assignment1.file Sec3           moremumbo.woot
FICTION.bak     Test-1.bak      mumble.txt
File-1.bat      Test-1.txt      mumbo.file
FundaOfIT.txt       Text-1.xtxt     myunix.txt
MyFave.txt      Text-2.xtxt     thistle.bak
Sec1            coursetext
Sec2            dooda.text
```

I need to move all the file present in the current directory "X.WORK" that ends with the letter "t" to the sub-directory Sec3,  how can I use the mv command to move them all together?

I apologise if it does look messy, this is my first question and I cannot get the code to look nicer and tidier for some reason.

Comment: You can use three backticks on the the line before a block of code and the line after the block to have it formatted as code. There has to be a blank line before and after the backticks.   BTW, The stack exchange editor has built-in help, click on the `?`, then on the Advanced Help link - https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

This is basic shell globbing:

```
mv ./*t Sec3/
```

The shell (**NOT** `mv` - this is a *very* important distinction, well worth remembering) will expand this to:

```
mv ./moremumbo.woot ./mumble.txt ./Test-1.txt ./FundaOfIT.txt ./Text-1.xtxt ./myunix.txt ./MyFave.txt ./Text-2.xtxt ./coursetext ./dooda.text Sec3/
```

(although, probably sorted, not in that order. Try it with `echo` or `ls -ld` instead of `mv` to see the sort order)

BTW, it's good habit to use the `./` prefix even though it isn't necessary.  This is to safeguard against an unfortunately named file accidentally (or malicuously) being interpreted as an option by `mv`.   e.g. if there was a file name `-t` in the directory, `*t` (without the `./` prefix) would expand to include that in the argument list and `mv` would interpret it as an option, not a filename.  For GNU `mv`, `-t` (short for `--target-directory`) treats the next argument as the target directory to move files to (it allows you to put the target directory *before* the other args, rather than after them).

It's also good practice to use the trailing `/` on a directory name.  It's a safeguard against accidentally overwriting or creating a file when you intended to move or copy (or rsync, whatever) a file into a directory.